# 410 push subscription has unsubscribed or expired

Tags: web-push

Our web push notification was just working fine but recently we noticed that the end points are expiring in less than one day and when we try to send notification initially it was going just fine but later it stopped delivering and when we checked we found that it was giving status code 410

the message was

> 410 push subscription has unsubscribed or expired

we searched google and found several links which says we need to resubscribe every time the link expire by sending old and new tokens and save that in db but the problem is we have huge no of subscriber and doing that for every one is not tenable. above all people will not open site again and again and if resubscribe can be achieved only when customer opens site again then lots of end points will be dead as people rarely return to site again and again except few very popular sites.

so is there any way we can update the new endpoints by exchanging the old endpoints through php at server end without depending on clients?

they have already subscribed to we have their end points which expired.

or is there anyway we can extend the expiry of generated endpoints at very first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must listen to the `pushsubscriptionchange` in the service worker, otherwise you will lose all the subscribers after some time: the subscriptions have a duration and then are replaced automatically.

You can see a real example of `pushsubscriptionchange` definition here:

https://pushpad.xyz/service-worker.js

Then on the server you need to replace the old endpoint with the new one.

Comment: i had seen your other answer and i highly doubt the validity of this approach as there is high chance that laptop or computer is not opened by end users and in that case all subscription will expire, so there must be some way we can update at server end

Comment: @jivasen the `pushsubscriptionchange` event is triggered by the user browser... so the device is always turned on in that moment. Read [the standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/) if you don't believe me.

Comment: as this is not yet implemented in chrome so there is no way we should rely on this. chrome is being used by 80% worldwide

Comment: @jivasen `pushsubscriptionchange` works properly in Chrome: [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/pushsubscriptionchange_event#browser_compatibility). I can also see from our logs that we receive thousands of requests from Chrome for that event.

Comment: @collimarco interesting example. anybody knows why they listen to the 'push' event a second time?

Comment: @SteMa It's for historical reasons... Old versions of Chrome did not support the payload (content) of the notifications, so you only received a push signal and then you had to fetch the content of notifications from the application server. Current versions support a notification payload, so you can use a simpler handler for the `push` event and simply display the notification.

Comment: @collimarco chrome does not work in chrome, check the 
 [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/pushsubscriptionchange_event#browser_compatibility)

Comment: Instead of listening to the push subscription change, would it be a viable alternative to just send the active subscription to the server every time the website is opened?

Comment: @FlorianWalther Yes, that is a good fallback. For example in our docs we recommend this approach: `if (sessionStorage.getItem('notifications') != 'subscribed') pushpad('subscribe', function () { sessionStorage.setItem('notifications', 'subscribed'); });`. You can also replace `pushpad('subscribe')` with your own library, but the concept is that sending the current subscription to the server *once per session* is a good idea and can work as a fallback.